# Как записать соответствующие условию дом элементы в объект ,а потом обратиться к ним через их порядковый номер?

Tags: jquery

```
<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding gallery_search" type="text" placeholder="Поиск по названию ..">



$(".gallery_search").on('keyup',function(e){
        var input, filter, container, title, titletext, masonryItem, simpleItem;
        filter = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        container = $(".mein-katalog");
        title = $(".mein-katalog .gallery-full .catatlog-title");
        container.find(".gallery-full").hide();
        container.find(".masonry-item").removeClass("gallery-item-big");
        masonryItem = new Object();
        simpleItem = new Object();
        $(".masonry-item").filter(function() { return  }).addClass(<class>);
        title.each(function(index){
            titletext = $(this).text();
            if (titletext.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                if($(this).parents(".gallery-full").hasClass("masonry-item")){
                    masonryItem[index] = $(this).parents(".masonry-item");
                }
                else{
                    simpleItem[index] = $(this).parents(".gallery-full");
                }
            }
        });
        masonryItem.eq(0).addClass("gallery-item-big");
        masonryItem.eq(7).addClass("gallery-item-big");
        masonryItem.eq(10).addClass("gallery-item-big");
        masonryItem.eq(17).addClass("gallery-item-big");
        masonryItem.show();
        simpleItem.fadeIn();
        $('.gallery-row.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
            $('.gallery-row.grid').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',

            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: хочу  найти в дом дереве все соответствующие условию элементы и добавить класс

Answer (score 0):

```
$(<selector>).filter(function() { return <check condition on this>; }).addClass(<class>);
```

Comment: а как в фильтре найти заголовок и найти подстроку в нем?

Comment: я этот код находит нужные елементы выбирает в них заголовок и если в нем есть под строка, находит родительский элемент и добавляет в объект ,но это не дом объект получился и не могу обратиться через eq()